# Import from csv into mongo collection with something like "group by" beforehand

Tags: mongodb

I would like to import a csv file into a mongo collection, however, the data is not exactly as i want it to be inside the collection.

I have the following csv file: (simplified)

```
city_id, city_name, street_id, street_name    
1,city1,1,street1
1,city1,2,street2
1,city1,3,street3
1,city1,4,street4
1,city1,5,street5
2,city2,1,street1
2,city2,2,street2
2,city2,3,street3
2,city2,4,street4
2,city2,5,street5
2,city2,6,street6
2,city2,7,street7
```

After the import i would want the imported collection to look like this:

```
    {
        city_id: 1,
        city_name: "city1",
        streets: [
                    {
                     street_id: 1,
                     street_name: street1 
                    },
                    {
                     street_id: 2,
                     street_name: street2 
                    },
                    {
                     street_id: 3,
                     street_name: street3 
                    },
                    {
                     street_id: 4,
                     street_name: street4
                    },
                    {
                     street_id: 5,
                     street_name: street5
                    }
                ]
    },
    {
        city_id: 2,
        city_name: "city2",
        streets: [
                    {
                     street_id: 1,
                     street_name: street1 
                    },
                    {
                     street_id: 2,
                     street_name: street2 
                    },
                    {
                     street_id: 3,
                     street_name: street3 
                    },
                    {
                     street_id: 4,
                     street_name: street4
                    },
                    {
                     street_id: 5,
                     street_name: street5
                    },
                    {
                     street_id: 6,
                     street_name: street6
                    },
                    {
                     street_id: 7,
                     street_name: street7
                    }

                ]
    }
```

Can this be done in a relatively easy manner?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. import data

> mongoimport.exe /file:city.csv /type:csv /headerline

2. using aggreagtion framwork combine and reshape document

   ```
   db.city.aggregate([
   {$group:{ 
       "_id":{"id":"$city_id","city_name":"$city_name" },
       "streets": { $push:  { street_id: "$street_id", street_name: "$street_name" } }
       }},
   {$project:{
       "_id":0,
       "city_id":"$_id.id",
       "city_name":"$_id.city_name",
       "streets":1 
       }},
       {$out:"cities"}
   ])
   ```
3. check **cities** collection for results

Comment: Amazing, it did the job, however i cant verify that it is 100% bugs free since the collection is more than 45,000 documents long :)

Comment: hmm, just for on random samples like cityID: 308, 374,563 :-)

Comment: I didn't understood why i got the downvote however :/